# Mysql LONGTEXT With timestamp string to actual TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I'm stumped on this one and need some help for the first time.

I've got a database field which is mysql LONGTEXT, with a string for a timestamp, eg, the string "1448386279"

I need to get that into a proper MySql TIMESTAMP field.

So

```
insert into temp (timestampfield) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1448377601'));
insert into temp (timestampfield) values(cast('1448377601' as time));
insert into temp (timestampfield) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(cast('1448377601' as UNSIGNED)));
```

all insert null into the timestamp field (temp is a real table, not a temporary table, I just named it badly!).

Any help you can give on this would be GREATLY appreciated!

Regards,
BlakeyUK

Comment: Try: [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function.

Comment: Ah, that's it. I'd gotten my Unix functions mixed up. Thanks !

Comment: Ah, thats not it. That returns a formatted string. I need a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `timestampfield` is a datetime column, then you could use [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function:

```
insert into temp (timestampfield) values (from_unixtime('1448377601'))
```

please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7636e/1).

Comment: Sorry, just re-reading everything. Just to clarify, I actually WANT a Unix timestamp, but what I'm starting with is a string of an integer representation of a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I'm an idiot. MySQL timestamp is NOT a unix timestamp. What I need is a simple INTEGER field to store that.